# using strtotime with datetimepicker and adding 1 day

Tags: php, datetimepicker

I'm saving to my database in the column 'time' in this format (user input using datetimepicker):

```
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
```

Example: 07-31-2014 03:37 am

I also have a column named 'status'. If the 'time' (the time saved in the column) + 24 hours surpasses the current time() then 'status' should = 'Expired'. Below is my attempt, but I think strtotime is not interpreting my timestamp as it's marking everything as Expired... example: 08-19-2014 02:05 am   Expired

```
if( (strtotime($row['time'] . "+1 days")) < time()) { $row['status'] = 'Expired'; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are getting date from database like in this format "07-31-2014 03:37 am".

You need to convert it and format it as strtotime readable one like below.

```
list($month,$day,$year,$hour,$minute) = preg_split("/[-\s:]+/", $row['time']);  

$row['time'] = $year."-".$month."-".$day." ".$hour.":".$minute.":00";
```

Try it.